# Loading indicator when firebase is retrieving data from real time database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simpel angular.js website with a ng-repeat div. In that div it repeats the data from the firebase realtime database.

When the page loads there is nothing in that ng-repeat object so the div is empty. But when firebase has made the websocket connection the data is displayed in the ng-repeat. 
Now my question is, can I show a loading indicator in the time were the page has loaded and firebase has downloaded the data. Because now the page loads and you have an empty div. After 1 sec firebase has loaded the data in.

---

**1 solution that did not work**

```
$scope.$watch('messages', function() {
 if ($scope.messages.$resolved === true) {
     document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
 }
}, true);
```

The problem with this solution is that if there is no data to display the loading div will stay there forever.

**1 solutions I think might work**

Store the latest response from the firebase database in a cache.json file. When a users loads the page you first load in that file and after that you replace it with the actual data from the firebase database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to help out without more of your code. If you could paste how you populate messages that would really help. I'm going to assume you're using angularFire for this so here's your answer:

```
$scope.loading = true;
$firebaseArray(...child('messages')).$loaded().then(function(){
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

This sets loading to true right before the call is made, and then back to false right after.

Comment: Thank you very much this solution solved the problem.

Comment: Hi,I have question regarding this code, is there away to do it more "globally"? instead to add $scope.loading = true; for each data request from firbase, add on some global fetching data request. so when there is somewhere in the code request from firbase the loader will be shown.